# XSLT format-date for an attribute

Tags: java, xml, xslt, formatdatetime

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd created_at="2016-12-15T15:02:55Z">
  <title created_at="2016-12-15T15:02:55Z">Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist created_at="2016-12-15T15:02:55Z">Bob Dylan</artist>
  <cover created_at="2016-12-15T15:02:55Z"/>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
</cd>
```

I want to format all occurrences of created_at attribute

```
input format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
output format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I am currently using this following xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Edit dates to conform to dbunit format-->
<xsl:template match="@created_at">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
            <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="@created_at"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="formatdate">
    <xsl:param name="datestr" />
    <!-- input format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ -->
    <!-- output format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS -->

    <xsl:variable name="datetext">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($datestr,'T')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="timetext">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,12,18)" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($datetext, ' ', $timetext)" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However as I debug through the transformation xslt it does not seem to enter the formatdate call-template. Is my xpath wrong? I found articles on modifying the node, but not the attribute. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:template match="@created_at">
    <xsl:attribute name="created_at">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(., 'T', ' '), 1, 19)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note: you cannot use `xsl:copy` if you want to change an attribute's value.

Answer (score 2):

From your post, it sounds like all you need is simple string processing.

#### Why your code isn't working the way you want

You're handling the `@created_at` attributes with this template:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@created_at">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
            <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="@created_at"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The kicker here is that you're using `<xsl:copy>`.  When used with attributes, `<xsl:copy>` copies the entire attribute, name and value both.  And since attributes can't contain any children, the children of your `<xsl:copy>` instruction are ignored -- so the XSLT processor never evaluates the `<xsl:call-template name="formatdate">` instruction.

#### A different approach that works

Instead of using `<xsl:copy>`, you need to instead use `<xsl:attribute>` to create an attribute in a way where you can also specify the value.  In this case, you already know the name of the attribute you want to create, so you could hard-code the name value as `created_at`.  For a more flexible approach, you could instead give the name value as `{name(.)}` -- this just grabs the name of the attribute being processed, which is closer in behavior to what you probably thought `<xsl:copy>` would do.  :)

It is also possible to produce the desired string in a single `xsl:value-of` expression, without relying on so many variables.

```xml
<xsl:template match="@created_at">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., 'T'), ' ', substring-before(substring-after(., 'T'), 'Z'))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Breaking down that `select` statement:

- Use `concat()` to stitch together multiple bits of string.
- Use `substring-before(., 'T')` to grab everything before the `T` -- that's the date portion.
- `' '` adds the single space in the middle.
- `substring-before(substring-after(., 'T'), 'Z')` --

  - The inner expression `substring-after(., 'T')` grabs everything after the `T` -- that's the time portion.
  - However, there's that pesky `Z` on the end, so we use `substring-before` as the outer expression to lop that off.

No need for variables, and it gets the job done.  Confirmed to work with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: You are assuming that the timezone will always be `Z`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Indeed. A certain kind of assumption is always needed when creating examples based on other folks' posted content.  I could turn your statement around and say that you're assuming that the date-time will always be 19 characters long.  :)  We both made assumptions here based on what we have in front of us.  FWIW, I like your use of `translate`: quite elegant.  I also think my approach is useful as a different example of string munging.

Comment: Well, assuming that the **format** will be constant is quite different from assuming that the **data** will be constant. If I thought that the timezone will always be `Z`, I would have gone with just `<xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'TZ', ' ')" />`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, interesting -- I expected that to result in extra whitespace in the attribute value, but lo, there isn't any.  :)  I seldom use `translate` as I deal mostly with CJK, and I simply haven't had occasion to use it much.  I'm also spoiled by working more with XPath 2.0 and up, so I've grown accustomed to `replace` and regex instead -- and `replace` doesn't auto-trim whitespace on the ends of the result string.  Thank you for the learning opportunity.

Comment: "`replace` *doesn't auto-trim whitespace on the ends of the result string*" Neither does `translate()`.  The point here that there is only one space in the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Edit dates to conform to dbunit format-->
<xsl:template match="@created_at">    
    <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
        <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template name="formatdate">
    <xsl:param name="datestr" />
    <!-- input format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ -->
    <!-- output format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS -->

    <xsl:variable name="datetext">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($datestr,'T')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="timetext">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,12,8)" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:attribute name="created_at">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($datetext, ' ', $timetext)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```